# Writing Dataset/Dataframe to HDFS directory without name of the column after partitionBy() :Spark 2.1.0

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, partition-by

I am using partitionBy() to partition the dataset/dataframe by some ID. But, when the file is written it is creating the directory with name and value of the column seperated by "="  symbol.

```
Seq<String> partitionCols = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList("alert_pas_documentid"));
                fnDatasetWithDocumentID.write().mode("overwrite").partitionBy(partitionCols).json("/user/creando/cdx/alert_pas/");
```

How to avoid getting the column name and "=" symbol. Here is the sample directory created.

```
/user/creando/cdx/inv_devices/inv_devices_documentid=700001_596970dba94c040001381a71_700001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of repartitioning with the writer, you can repartition the dataset before the writing, ie:

```
Seq<Column> partitionCols = ...
fnDatasetWithDocumentID.repartition(partitionCols).write().mode("overwrite").json("/user/creando/cdx/alert_pas/");
```

Comment: I tried this option but when i execute the spark job the spark job does not goto the phase of RUNNING. Instead, it always shows 18/04/21 16:27:04 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1522909218432_0088 (state: ACCEPTED)

Comment: Application Report :
        Application-Id : application_1522909218432_0088
        Application-Name : com.cisco.sdp.cdx.InventoryStreamingJob.InventoryStreaming
        Application-Type : SPARK
        User : creando
        Queue : root.creando
        Start-Time : 1524327876389
        Finish-Time : 0
        Progress : 0%
        State : ACCEPTED
        Final-State : UNDEFINED
        Tracking-URL : N/A
        RPC Port : -1
        AM Host : N/A
        Aggregate Resource Allocation : 0 MB-seconds, 0 vcore-seconds
        Diagnostics :